# Why is my div not reaching the top of my page?

Tags: html, css

https://ibb.co/z5S7Kqh <-- Here you can see the issue. My fixed div Reaches fully to the left and right properly but there is a gap where you can see the background. here is the css code...

```css
body {
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: rgb(0, 255, 97);
  background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40);
  align-self: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.topBar {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-shadow: -0.05em -0.05em rgb(40, 40, 40);
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="topBar">
  <h1 id="title" onclick="openTab('https://www.jfkairport.com/')">Jhon F. Kennedy international Airport - Real Time Air Tracking</h1>
</div>
```

(Don't worry bout the JFk Airport bit. The onclick and its JS function work.)

Comment: Does your `#topBar` have `top: 0;` anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset all elements's default padding and margin by adding this at the top of your css:

```css
*, ::before, ::after{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is it resets all default padding and margin to zero which might be the things he is using. That hammer thinks everything is a nail.